# How to isolate charge circuit from drain circuit

Tags: 12v, charge

I am installing a 5k winch on a car hauler trailer.  I will power the winch from a deep cycle battery permanently installed on the trailer.  I want to keep the battery charged by connecting it to the charge circuit from my trailer wiring harness.  The issue is that the winch pulls more amps than the charge circuit supplies.  What do I need to do to make sure that the power for the winch only pulls from the battery and not from the charge circuit?  I realize that I could just unplug the trailer from the truck when I use the winch, but I was looking for a more elegant and automatic solution.

---

Thank you all for your input and help.  It looks like my best solution is a manual switch.  I was REALLY hoping for something more idiot proof, but looks like this idiot will just need to learn to check the switch.

Have a great day

Comment: Design the charge circuit in a way that it will not care? Like most likely all charge circuits out there do...

Comment: as long as the charger works, the battery will restore itself after draining.  i.e. 100 amps for 1 minute may take > 10 minutes @ 10A

Comment: Why would you want to... assuming the alternator is powerful enough to run the winch. Adding circuitry to disconnect if the engine is not running would be prudent though. You would not want to drain the truck battery when it isn't running.

Comment: The problem is that the charge circuit going to the trailer is 10A and small gauge wire.  If I try to run the winch while this line is connected, I will blow the fuse or melt the wire.

Answer (score 1):

What you really want is a current limiter on your charge circuit which it may already have. Check the specs on it.

For a more manual solution you can do this with an double pole switch to the winch (you may want a switch anyway). In the ON position it connects the battery to the winch but in the off position it connects the battery to the charging circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIIZHH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Add a interlock of some kind so you are encouraged to leave the switch in the OFF position (like for example using a key switch with the key on the same ring as the one for the vehicle doing the towing).

Comment: +1 That might be rather a beefy switch though, you may need to use the switch to operate a relay/contactor.

Comment: They make beefy winch operation switches that can be connected to do exactly what @ratchet_freak has described. The ones I have used have a spring loaded action so that you have to hold it in place to operate the winch and the spring returns the switch to the opposite connection.

Comment: I think this is going to be my best solution.  I am ordering a switch that will force me to choose WINCH or CHARGE.  https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B001V7TL10/ref=ox_sc_act_title_1?smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER&psc=1

Answer (score 1):

Your truck charging system already deals with this problem related to its own battery when you are engaging the starter and the charging system is not yet operating. So you should have little concern to simply use the truck charging system to charge the remote battery on the trailer.

You do want to consider installing a battery isolator under the hood of the truck so that the drain on the trailer battery operating the winch does not also drain the battery in the truck. The typical battery isolator is simple a box with two high current diodes connected to binding bolts on its side. The diodes are fed from the output of the truck's alternator to the anodes of the two diodes. The cathode of one diode feeds out to the remote trailer battery wiring and the other diode feeds into the V+ power distribution and battery in the truck where the alternator output originally connected.

You can purchase these battery isolators at RV equipment shops and some auto parts stores.

Comment: I looked at this and they are dependent on having easy access to the ignition circuit for switching.  This circuit does not go back to the trailer plug.

Comment: @Scott - In every instance where I had need to support charging a battery in a trailer location I had to run heavy gauge wire from the battery splitter out to the rear of the vehicle where a special trailer piug with large sized electrical contacts was mounted.